# C++ XCode Linking Libraries for jsoncpp

Tags: c++, xcode

I am stuck between either not being able to find symbols, due to having  included but not being able to find the .cpp,  and when i add the library, I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   buildscons/linux-gcc-4.2.1/src/lib_json/libjson_linux-gcc-4.2.1_libmt.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Users/kural/Documents/glia/build/Debug/glia
>   Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap logout

How to fix this?  I'm using XCode 3.2

Comment: Looks like your wacky `lib_json` library is not being copied into your compiled app package.  What kind of app is this, anyways?  Why do I see "linux" all over the paths?

Comment: linux is one of the platform "targets" for the scons builder jsoncpp is using. That's also supposedly the one for OS X ...  Don't know why it isn't being copied because the library exists in that exact path. Thx!